# cmake targeting Visual Studio with explicit platform toolset does not find boost

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to generate a Visual Studio 2013 project like this:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" -T "v100" ..
```

My project is using some static Boost libraries like `system`. With `Boost_DEBUG` enabled, I get the following output:

```
[ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_53;libboost_system-vc120-mt;libboost_system-mt-1_53;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-1_53;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s;libboost_system-mt-s-1_53;libboost_system-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_53;libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_system-mt-gd-1_53;libboost_system-mt-gd;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_53;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_system-mt-s-gd-1_53;libboost_system-mt-s-gd

[...]

CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1111 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.53.0

  Boost include path: C:/Boost/boost_1_53_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_thread
          boost_date_time

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

I *guess* that cmake doesn't find the boost libraries because it searches for wrong file names. I tell it to generate a project with target platform `v100`, so it should search for `libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_53`, not `libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_53`, right? My installed Boost release does not include `vc120` libraries, and I use other libraries that are only available as `vc100`. So how do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the `FindBoost` module (or rather it not being updated for the presence of `-T`). You might want to bring this up on the CMake mailing list (cmake@cmake.org).